# float:none; formatting affects background-color of div?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to understand the behavior of `float` and `clear`. For that reason I've created a tiny example [(avaiable on jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/faq9h/1/) for experimenting:

HTML:

```
<div class="left">A</div>
<div class="custom">B</div>
<div class="left">C</div>
<div class="left">D</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: blue;
    color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.custom {
    float: none;
}​
```

First of all I do not understand why the `background-color: blue;` directive seems lost for B.

[image: original]

And secondly it's not clear to me, why removing `margin: 3px;` statement results in this:

[image: margin removed]

Thank you in advance for your help or links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directive isn't being lost for B - it's just that the floated elements surrounding it are pushing the text outside of the div. Remove the background colour from the floated elements, and you can see things a bit clearer:

http://jsfiddle.net/faq9h/3/

When you remove the margin (as in your second image), what you're actually seeing is the background of C showing through underneath the B text.

A quick way of fixing this is to add `display: inline-block` to the non-floated element:

http://jsfiddle.net/faq9h/4/

Then your boxes will appear as A C D B.

As for understanding what's going on: [this is an excellent article](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

Comment: thank you for reply and especially for the modified samples on jsfiddle. I gained some more understanding, but I still have to learn some more stuff :)..